# Paypal Selenium automation Accept Cookies not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, paypal

It looks like paypal has updated their plugin lately and my code stopped working. I tried using Selenium IDE but when I record using it I do not see the Accept Cookie modal popup. I am able to get pass login as below, but I tried many different way to get to submit payment button with no luck. Help appreciated.

```
public IDictionary<string, object> vars { get; private set; }
vars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
vars["WindowHandles"] = _driver.WindowHandles;
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".paypal-button")).Click();
vars["win8061"] = waitForWindow(2000);
vars["root"] = _driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
_driver.SwitchTo().Window(vars["win8061"].ToString());
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys(paypalEmail);
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnNext")).Click();
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(paypalPassword);
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin")).Click();
//The problem is here!!!
var element = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("payment-submit-btn"));
Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
builder.MoveToElement(element).Perform();

        public string waitForWindow(int timeout)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(timeout);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }
            var whNow = ((IReadOnlyCollection<object>)_driver.WindowHandles).ToList();
            var whThen = ((IReadOnlyCollection<object>)vars["WindowHandles"]).ToList();
            if (whNow.Count > whThen.Count)
            {
                return whNow.Except(whThen).First().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return whNow.First().ToString();
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue recently after PayPal made some kind of changes to their "Pay" button. All of the sudden it stopped working. Below is what worked for me. There is no logic behind it, besides "just because it works".
After PayPal login; in your case after:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin")).Click();
```

Use:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("acceptAllButton")).Click();

try
{
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("payment-submit-btn")).Click();
}
catch
{
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("payment-submit-btn")).Click();
}
```